Starting Docker process caused : runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "flask": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
I am trying to dockerize a my python-flask application but i am getting this error.
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "flask": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

My Dockerfile is :
FROM python:3.9-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 5000


CMD ["flask", "run"]

Commands i ran :
docker build -t my-flask-app .
docker run -p 5000:5000 (My image ID)

Expected : Flask web should run on port 5000
Actual Result :
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "flask": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.


I assume your application works correctly locally. Please update your question with the content of the requirements.txt in the folder from which you're running docker build. The error suggests that you're not installing Flask in the container. Does the folder include .dockerignore file?

Here's a minimal project to get you started.
├── app.py
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
└── wsgi.py

 Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run"]

 requirements.txt ( You need to list the Flask package here because it provides the flask command you are trying to run.)
Flask==3.0.3

I'm not sure what your app looks like, but these two minimal files demonstrate that this setup works.
 app.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

 wsgi.py
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


